# Run lldb command in Python script

Tags: python, lldb

I wrote a python script for lldb (check_assert.py) and now I'm writing another script called check_params.py.
I've also created a command line execution for check_assert.py (check_assert).
how can I execute check_asset inside the ceck_params.py script?

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand and then help

Answer (score 0):

you can use os lib in the following way, not sure what your question is exactly

```
import os
os.system("python check_asset.py")
```